# ANR when I am starting a service

Tags: android, android-service

I am using a service to download heavy files from the web.but when the files are being downloaded I am unable to interact with the app. What is the best way for this .
**I am downloading files that are about 10 MB and I want the user to interact with app while the files are downloaded**
Please find the my service code.

```
public static class MyService extends Service {
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        public MyService(){
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
            System.out.println("service started");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(Description.this, "Downloading content...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            GetShowsInfo(downloadEpisodeMedia(episode_id));
            RequestDownloads();


            File cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Folder Name");
            listf(cacheDir,files);
            mediaPlayerflag=true;
            //progressBarLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

            nowPlayingEpisode=categoryName;
            //NowPlayingEpisode.setText("Now Playing "+episodeArrayList.get(position).getName());

            textView_MediaPlayer.setText(nowPlayingEpisode);
            //textView_EpisodeCount.setText(episodeCount);
            playOnebyOneMedia();

            //  StoreInfo(GetCategories());
            //StoreDescription(GetDescription());
            return START_STICKY;
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            System.out.println("service stopped");
            super.onDestroy();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Add logcat message and why you are doing textView_MediaPlayer.setText from service?

Comment: I think instead of service you should consider about asynctask..

Comment: I am downloading files that are about 10 MB and I want the user to interact with app while the files are downloaded

Comment: You can do the same from asynctask... its better than service (in you case)

Comment: Can I interact with the app while files is being downloaded ? Can you share a snippet

Comment: Yes read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html and see kalyan has given you alink of example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IntentService` instead of `Service`. `IntentService` uses a separate thread to handle intents. So it wont block your main thread. `onStartCommand` method of your service runs in main thread and blocks it for too long time and causes ANR.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are performing very large operations on the UI thread like downloading files..`ANR` comes when the UI thread perform the long running operations..try to do it with using `AsynchTask` or threads..then you can avoid `ANR`..

check this link for download file in AsynchTask example..[AsynckTask example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/)

Comment: I am downloading files that are about 10 MB and I want the user to interact with app while the files are downloaded